# How to Save Menu item Checked state in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

In my app's Menu i have 2 items, one of them is Checkable and i want to save his state using SharedPreferences. 
Here is my code:
**MainActivity**

```
 MenuItem bubu1;
 boolean isChecked;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

 bubu1.setChecked(getFromSP("cec1"));
  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_rate_us:

            break;
        case R.id.action_enab:
            saveInSp("cec1",isChecked);
            if (bubu1.isChecked()) {
                bubu1.setChecked(false);

            }else{

                bubu1.setChecked(true);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private boolean getFromSP(String key){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}

private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

**Menu xml**

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_enab"
    android:title="@string/enab"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="false"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_rate_us"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_rate_us"/>
```

**And here is the error i get:**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: dia.it.solutions.lagcleaner, PID: 6143
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dia.it.solutions.lagcleaner/dia.it.solutions.lagcleaner.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at dia.it.solutions.lagcleaner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

From the error, i understand that the app crashes because of the line 95 from MainActivity and here is the 95 line:

> bubu1.setChecked(getFromSP("cec1"));

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You need to initialize `bubu1` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bubu1` is `null` in `onCreate` Method becuase it has not been initialized.
Change your code to

```
    MenuItem bubu1;
        boolean isChecked;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            bubu1 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_enab);
            bubu1.setChecked(getFromSP("cec1"));
            return true;
        }
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_rate_us:

                break;
            case R.id.action_enab:

                if (bubu1.isChecked()) {
                    bubu1.setChecked(false);
                    saveInSp("cec1",false);
                }else{

                    bubu1.setChecked(true);
                      saveInSp("cec1",true);
                }
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Now i don't get any error, but after i restart the app the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: make sure you are calling saveInSp method with correct key value

Comment: there was a mistake in my code i have resolved it just now, Please check it once again i m sure this will work perfect

Comment: how can i check in OnCreate if cec1 is true ?

Comment: You can check if it true but you have to set the menu item state in `onCreateOptionsMenu` because `onCreateOptionsMenu` method is called after the `onCreate` method so the menu item will always null in `onCreate` Method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113536/discussion-between-george-lungu-and-gopal-singh-sirvi).

Answer (score 0):

`bubu1` is `null` , you must have to initialize view before using it.